# git update hook: Finding all revs being committed

Tags: git, hook

I'm creating an update hook so that our central git repository can do some simple sanity checks of each file in each commit.  However, I don't know how to make git cough up the names of all of the commits in a "push".

No matter how many commits the client is pushing, the update hook is called just once (by design).  For example, suppose that HEAD is e2706ec, and I create two commits:

```
$ echo 'date' >>foo && git commit -am'Touched foo'
[master e5c9682] Touched foo
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ echo 'date' >>bar && git commit -am'Touched bar'
[master bdc1fd1] Touched bar
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Then I push the code to the central repository:

```
$ git push
```

The .git/hooks/update script gets called once with these arguments:

- refs/heads/master
- e2706ec31e51b9bbd4010e79fd7186089c59690e
- bdc1fd17e8209bbb987b5358a0b49b20d9589103

Git passes to the update hook the ref_name, old_rev, and new_rev.  What it doesn't pass are the names of any revs between old_rev and new_rev (in this case, e5c9682).

Given old_rev and new_rev, what is the git spell to get each rev that the client is attempting to push?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git rev-list ^old_rev new_rev`

It's list all commit between this two commit

Comment: Yes, this is correct. http://progit.org/book/ch7-4.html gives some more concrete examples.